# Angular 4 Reactive form reset() function shows error messages on reset

Tags: angular

Sample code

```
<input type="text" formControlName="firstName" class="form-control col-md-11" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submittedCreateUserForm && fCreateuser.firstName.errors }" placeholder="First Name" />
<div *ngIf="submittedCreateUserForm && fCreateArticle.firstName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="fCreateuser.firstName.errors.required" style="color:red">First Name is required</div>
</div>
```

On calling `reset()` function it will display error message "***First Name is required***" with input box color to red.

Comment: Add some code so we see what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sample Code: <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" class="form-control col-md-11" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submittedCreateUserForm && fCreateuser.firstName.errors }" placeholder="First Name" />
<div *ngIf="submittedCreateUserForm && fCreateArticle.firstName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
 <div *ngIf="fCreateuser.firstName.errors.required" style="color:red">First Name is required</div>
</div>

Comment: Add the reset function code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug currently in angular. When we use reset() on formGroup, it should does not properly reset the state (pristine and untocuhed). To overcome this, we ned to to reset and setError to null on every controls in the formGroup.
For Ex:

```
this.questionForm = this._fb.group({
      title: [null, Validators.required],
      information: [''],
    });
```

To properly reset questioForm so that i does not show any validation errors on the view part,

```
Object.keys(this.questionForm.controls).forEach(controlName => {
  this.questionForm.controls[controlName].reset();
  this.questionForm.controls[controlName].setErrors(null);
});
```

You can chekc their [git repo here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15741)